NFCService API Not Triggering 'then' Clause on Successful NFC Read
I'm encountering an issue with the NFCService API in a Lightning Web Component designed for mobile. When attempting to read an NFC tag, my mobile device vibrates and provides sound feedback, indicating the NFC tag was detected, but the code doesn't execute past nfcService.read().then(...). Here's what happens:
The NFC read is triggered, and the phone acknowledges the tag.
The expected logging and further processing in the .then() method does not occur, although error handling in .catch() executes when I press the 'Cancel' button.
This is my method for handling the read:
handleReadClick() {
   this.nfcService.read(options).then((result) => {
       // Process result and log to server
     }).catch((error) => {
       // Handle errors
     });
}

The NFC card works with other applications, so it seems specific to this API or how it's implemented in LWC. Has anyone experienced similar issues, or does anyone have insights on what might be going wrong?
Thank you for any help or guidance you can provide!
